# Magneto 2 Unable add category to cart price rule by clicking on checkbox

Tags: magento2

**Steps to reproduce (*)**

1. Marketing > Cart Price Rules > Add New Rule
2. Click on Action section.
3. Add conditions to Actions: choose "category", click on the ellipsis, see the input field, click "Open chooser", see the category tree
4. Try to add category by clicking checkbox

**Expected result (*)**

5. Category ID will appear in the input

**Actual result (*)**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateElement' of undefined
at Ext.tree.TreePanel.Enhanced.<anonymous> (category-checkbox-tree.js:249)
at Ext.util.Event.fire (ext-tree.js:29)
at Ext.tree.TreePanel.Enhanced.fireEvent (ext-tree.js:29)
at Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI.check (ext-tree-checkbox.js:193)
at ext-tree.js:9
at Ext.tree.TreeNode.expand (ext-tree.js:201)
at Ext.tree.CheckboxNodeUI.check (ext-tree-checkbox.js:162)
at El.Flyweight.<anonymous> (ext-tree.js:9)
at HTMLInputElement.h (ext-tree.js:33)
at HTMLInputElement.M (legacy-build.min.js:8)
```

[image]

Comment: what your magento version ?

Comment: @ThànhTrungTô Magento version is 2.3.5

Comment: i can't replicate error.my version is 2.3.5 p1 https://www.loom.com/share/d460ed4bf1404bc791d0ef1651d057e0

Comment: @ThànhTrungTô kindly flow correct steps. given above

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer to this question.**

- You have to override [ Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\NewActionHtml ]
- Create folder inside [ app/code/SalesRuleCustom/ModuleSalesRule ]

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'salesrulecustom_ModuleSalesRule',
__DIR__
);
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\NewActionHtml" type="SalesRuleCustom\ModuleSalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\NewActionHtml" />
</config>
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="salesrulecustom_ModuleSalesRule" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\NewActionHtml.php**

```
<?php

 namespace SalesRuleCustom\ModuleSalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
 use Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition;
 use Magento\SalesRule\Controller\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote;
 use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;

 class NewActionHtml extends Quote implements HttpPostActionInterface
 {
/**
 * New action html action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()
        ->getParam('id');
    $formName = $this->getRequest()
        ->getParam('form_namespace');

    $jsFormObject = $this->getRequest()
        ->getParam('form');

    $typeArr = explode('|', str_replace('-', '/', $this->getRequest()->getParam('type')));
    $type = $typeArr[0];

    $model = $this->_objectManager->create(
        $type
    )->setId(
        $id
    )->setType(
        $type
    )->setRule(
        $this->_objectManager->create(Rule::class)
    )->setPrefix(
        'actions'
    );
    if (!empty($typeArr[1])) {
        $model->setAttribute($typeArr[1]);
    }

    if ($model instanceof AbstractCondition) {
        $model->setJsFormObject($jsFormObject);
        $model->setFormName($formName);
        $html = $model->asHtmlRecursive();
    } else {
        $html = '';
    }
    $this->getResponse()
        ->setBody($html);
  }
}
```